# how convert this string json PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following string

```
[[[2401263,"Chelsea","Everton",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977131,39]],1,1,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.4400000",0],17,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2401266,"Newcastle","Arsenal",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977137,39]],0,0,1,[1,90,"2013-05-19T15:01:10.8430000",0,0,0],18,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",0,0],[2401267,"Southampton","Stoke City",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977139,39]],0,0,1,[1,180,"2013-05-19T15:02:56.8230000",0,0,0],18,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",0,0],[2401269,"Tottenham","Sunderland",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977143,39]],0,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.7070000",0,0,0],18,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",0,0],[2401270,"West Brom","Man Utd",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977145,39]],0,2,1,[1,90,"2013-05-19T15:03:06.0200000",0],17,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2401271,"Wigan","Aston Villa",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977147,39]],1,1,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.7530000",0],17,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2408847,"Dep La Coruna","Espanyol",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4979597,39]],0,0,1,[1,90,"2013-05-19T15:01:11.2030000",0,0,0],27,"/sports/soccer/spain_la_liga",0,0],[2408897,"Hercules","Mirandes",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4987070,39]],0,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.4570000",0],18,"/sports/soccer/spain_segunda",,],[2408960,"Korona Kielce","Jagiellonia Bialystok",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4999194,39]],1,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:54.3700000",0],17,"/sports/soccer/poland_ekstraklasa",,],[2412214,"Varnamo IFK","GAIS Goteborg",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4988445,39]],0,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.3800000",0],27,"/sports/soccer/sweden_superettan",,],[2412215,"Panos Ljungskile","Jonkopings Sodra",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4988447,39]],0,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:54.4000000",0],27,"/sports/soccer/sweden_superettan",,],[2413870,"PAOK Saloniki","Pas Giannina",1,"2013-05-19T15:15:00.0000000",[[4999196,39]],0,0,1,[1,570,"2013-05-19T15:15:36.1670000",0],18,"/sports/soccer/greece_super_league",,],[2417005,"Turkey U16","Russia U16",1,"2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",[[5001521,39]],1,0,1,[2,2790,"2013-05-19T15:02:31.6370000",0],0,"/sports/soccer/friendly_intl_u16",,],[2401264,"Liverpool","Queens P Rangers",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977133,39]],1,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.3470000",0],17,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2401268,"Swansea","Fulham",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977141,39]],0,1,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.8630000",0],17,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2408652,"Zenit St. Petersburg","Volga Nizhniy Novgorod",1,"2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",[[4987679,39]],1,1,1,[3,2790,"2013-05-19T15:18:21.6570000",0,0,0],24,"/sports/soccer/russia_premier_liga",0,0],[2411551,"Diosgyor Balaton","Kecskemet",1,"2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",[[4999186,39]],0,1,1,[3,2730,"2013-05-19T15:18:21.6230000",0,0,0],16,"/sports/soccer/hungary_nb_i",0,0],[2414581,"Utrecht","Heerenveen",1,"2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",[[4999188,39]],1,0,1,[3,2730,"2013-05-19T15:16:28.2570000",0],16,"/sports/soccer/netherlands_eredivisie",,],[2414656,"Roda","De Graafschap",1,"2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",[[4999190,39]],3,1,1,[3,2790,"2013-05-19T15:19:08.9100000",0],16,"/sports/soccer/netherlands_eerste_div",,],[2401265,"Man City","Norwich",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977135,39]],0,1,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:00:48.3170000",0],18,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2408690,"Sturm Graz","Ried",1,"2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",[[4986537,39]],1,1,1,[2,2790,"2013-05-19T15:04:14.3830000",0],16,"/sports/soccer/austria_bundesliga",,],[2401272,"West Ham","Reading",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977149,39]],1,0,1,[1,30,"2013-05-19T15:02:29.9830000",0],18,"/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",,],[2414909,"Peristeri","Ilisiakos BC",2,"2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",[[5001488,39]],48,49,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T13:58:54.3470000",0],5,"/sports/basketball/greece_a1",,],[2417273,"Istanbul Teknik Uni","Duzce Belediye",2,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[5001550,39]],16,26,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T15:09:41.7100000",0],6,"/sports/basketball/friendly",,],[2417087,"Benfica","Academica",2,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[5001548,39]],23,11,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T15:09:32.3000000",0],6,"/sports/basketball/portugal_liga_tmn",,],[2416259,"Edouard Roger-Vasselin [FRA]","Alejandro Falla [COL]",6,"2013-05-19T14:55:00.0000000",[[5000358,39]],3001,4000,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T04:13:48.0670000",0,3,0],2,"/sports/tennis/atp_nice",3,0],[2416856,"Flavia Pennetta [ITA]","Katarzyna Piter [POL]",6,"2013-05-19T10:00:00.0000000",[[5000441,39]],6000,5001,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T05:28:36.6800000",0,3,0],2,"/sports/tennis/wta_strasbourg_qualifiers",3,0],[2416854,"Marta Domachowska [POL]","Arantxa Parra Santonja [ESP]",6,"2013-05-19T09:30:00.0000000",[[5000437,39]],46001,33000,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T05:28:36.4700000",0,3,0],2,"/sports/tennis/wta_strasbourg_qualifiers",3,0],[2416265,"Finland ","USA ",8,"2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",[[5000330,39]],0,2,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T03:57:47.0200000",0],0,"/sports/ice_hockey/world_championship_2013",,],[2416824,"Sunrisers Hyderabad","Kolkata Knight Riders",22,"2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",[[5001544,39]],0,0,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T15:03:26.2830000",0],0,"/sports/cricket/indian_premier_league",,],[2417259,"El Jaish","Al Rayyan ",19,"2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",[[5001502,39]],1,2,1,[0,0,"2013-05-19T14:06:27.8300000",0],0,"/sports/volleyball/friendlies_international",,]],[[1,"Soccer",1,1,["1x2","Asians","O/U"]],[2,"Basketball",2,2,["ML","Spread","O/U"]],[6,"Tennis",6,6,["Winner","Handicap","O/U"]],[8,"Ice Hockey",8,8,["Match Winner","Spread","O/U"]],[22,"Cricket",22,22,["MoneyLine","Spread","O/U"]],[19,"Volleyball",19,19,["ML","Sets Handicap","O/U"]]]]
```

How can I convert this to JSON data with php for use in `json_decode()`?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "convert to JSON data". For example, to pass it to JavaScript, `echo $mystring` is sufficient.

Comment: Is your problem the extra commas at the end of some of the arrays?

Comment: There is nothing you have to do. Just pass it to `json_decode`: `$data = json_decode($my_string);`. If you have a particular problem, then you have to describe it. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Has anybody ever tried to actually validate that string, e.g. on http://jsonlint.com?

Comment: Apparently the JSON is invalid... you should fix the process that generates the JSON if you can.

Comment: @FelixKling Or use the workaround provided in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16637012/1553481).

Comment: @likeitlikeit: Sure, but solving the *actual* problem is always better ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I would agree. However, this is oftentimes out of control. The data is about football (soccer) teams. Might come from an official source, in the form that it does. Also, the question explicitly asks about converting. You seem to be the only guy here that actually understood the question though, so more power to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's easy:** This looks like JSON, but it isn't. Use the following code to transform it into something that `json_decode()` will accept:

```
$input = <<<EOL
[[[2401263,"Chelsea","Everton",1,"2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",[[4977131,39]],1$
EOL;

$input2 = str_replace(",,", ",null,", $input);
$json = str_replace(",]", "]", $input2);

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: @user1889527 You're welcome. Please accept the answer using the checkmark icon if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your string already looks like what JS Is expecting.

If your in doubt, then:

```
echo json_encode($String);
```

Comment: I agree..that's the one, I even included the link :)

Comment: please read question carefully

Comment: What do you get when you pass it to `json_decode`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the json is indeed invalid...

```
 "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league", <---- remove this one too.
            , <------------ another comma
```

too many commas, remove

```
[
[
    [
        2401263,
        "Chelsea",
        "Everton",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977131,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        1,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.4400000",
            0
        ],
        17,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2401266,
        "Newcastle",
        "Arsenal",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977137,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            90,
            "2013-05-19T15:01:10.8430000",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        2401267,
        "Southampton",
        "Stoke City",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977139,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            180,
            "2013-05-19T15:02:56.8230000",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        2401269,
        "Tottenham",
        "Sunderland",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977143,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.7070000",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league",
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        2401270,
        "West Brom",
        "Man Utd",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977145,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        2,
        1,
        [
            1,
            90,
            "2013-05-19T15:03:06.0200000",
            0
        ],
        17,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2401271,
        "Wigan",
        "Aston Villa",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977147,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        1,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.7530000",
            0
        ],
        17,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2408847,
        "Dep La Coruna",
        "Espanyol",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4979597,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            90,
            "2013-05-19T15:01:11.2030000",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        27,
        "/sports/soccer/spain_la_liga",
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        2408897,
        "Hercules",
        "Mirandes",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4987070,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.4570000",
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/spain_segunda"
    ],
    [
        2408960,
        "Korona Kielce",
        "Jagiellonia Bialystok",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4999194,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:54.3700000",
            0
        ],
        17,
        "/sports/soccer/poland_ekstraklasa"
    ],
    [
        2412214,
        "Varnamo IFK",
        "GAIS Goteborg",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4988445,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.3800000",
            0
        ],
        27,
        "/sports/soccer/sweden_superettan"
    ],
    [
        2412215,
        "Panos Ljungskile",
        "Jonkopings Sodra",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4988447,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:54.4000000",
            0
        ],
        27,
        "/sports/soccer/sweden_superettan"
    ],
    [
        2413870,
        "PAOK Saloniki",
        "Pas Giannina",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:15:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4999196,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            570,
            "2013-05-19T15:15:36.1670000",
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/greece_super_league"
    ],
    [
        2417005,
        "Turkey U16",
        "Russia U16",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5001521,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        0,
        1,
        [
            2,
            2790,
            "2013-05-19T15:02:31.6370000",
            0
        ],
        0,
        "/sports/soccer/friendly_intl_u16"
    ],
    [
        2401264,
        "Liverpool",
        "Queens P Rangers",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977133,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.3470000",
            0
        ],
        17,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2401268,
        "Swansea",
        "Fulham",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977141,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        1,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.8630000",
            0
        ],
        17,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2408652,
        "Zenit St. Petersburg",
        "Volga Nizhniy Novgorod",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4987679,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        1,
        1,
        [
            3,
            2790,
            "2013-05-19T15:18:21.6570000",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        24,
        "/sports/soccer/russia_premier_liga",
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        2411551,
        "Diosgyor Balaton",
        "Kecskemet",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4999186,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        1,
        1,
        [
            3,
            2730,
            "2013-05-19T15:18:21.6230000",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        16,
        "/sports/soccer/hungary_nb_i",
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        2414581,
        "Utrecht",
        "Heerenveen",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4999188,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        0,
        1,
        [
            3,
            2730,
            "2013-05-19T15:16:28.2570000",
            0
        ],
        16,
        "/sports/soccer/netherlands_eredivisie"
    ],
    [
        2414656,
        "Roda",
        "De Graafschap",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4999190,
                39
            ]
        ],
        3,
        1,
        1,
        [
            3,
            2790,
            "2013-05-19T15:19:08.9100000",
            0
        ],
        16,
        "/sports/soccer/netherlands_eerste_div"
    ],
    [
        2401265,
        "Man City",
        "Norwich",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977135,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        1,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:00:48.3170000",
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2408690,
        "Sturm Graz",
        "Ried",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4986537,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        1,
        1,
        [
            2,
            2790,
            "2013-05-19T15:04:14.3830000",
            0
        ],
        16,
        "/sports/soccer/austria_bundesliga"
    ],
    [
        2401272,
        "West Ham",
        "Reading",
        1,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                4977149,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        0,
        1,
        [
            1,
            30,
            "2013-05-19T15:02:29.9830000",
            0
        ],
        18,
        "/sports/soccer/england_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2414909,
        "Peristeri",
        "Ilisiakos BC",
        2,
        "2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5001488,
                39
            ]
        ],
        48,
        49,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T13:58:54.3470000",
            0
        ],
        5,
        "/sports/basketball/greece_a1"
    ],
    [
        2417273,
        "Istanbul Teknik Uni",
        "Duzce Belediye",
        2,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5001550,
                39
            ]
        ],
        16,
        26,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T15:09:41.7100000",
            0
        ],
        6,
        "/sports/basketball/friendly"
    ],
    [
        2417087,
        "Benfica",
        "Academica",
        2,
        "2013-05-19T15:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5001548,
                39
            ]
        ],
        23,
        11,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T15:09:32.3000000",
            0
        ],
        6,
        "/sports/basketball/portugal_liga_tmn"
    ],
    [
        2416259,
        "Edouard Roger-Vasselin [FRA]",
        "Alejandro Falla [COL]",
        6,
        "2013-05-19T14:55:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5000358,
                39
            ]
        ],
        3001,
        4000,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T04:13:48.0670000",
            0,
            3,
            0
        ],
        2,
        "/sports/tennis/atp_nice",
        3,
        0
    ],
    [
        2416856,
        "Flavia Pennetta [ITA]",
        "Katarzyna Piter [POL]",
        6,
        "2013-05-19T10:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5000441,
                39
            ]
        ],
        6000,
        5001,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T05:28:36.6800000",
            0,
            3,
            0
        ],
        2,
        "/sports/tennis/wta_strasbourg_qualifiers",
        3,
        0
    ],
    [
        2416854,
        "Marta Domachowska [POL]",
        "Arantxa Parra Santonja [ESP]",
        6,
        "2013-05-19T09:30:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5000437,
                39
            ]
        ],
        46001,
        33000,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T05:28:36.4700000",
            0,
            3,
            0
        ],
        2,
        "/sports/tennis/wta_strasbourg_qualifiers",
        3,
        0
    ],
    [
        2416265,
        "Finland ",
        "USA ",
        8,
        "2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5000330,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        2,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T03:57:47.0200000",
            0
        ],
        0,
        "/sports/ice_hockey/world_championship_2013"
    ],
    [
        2416824,
        "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
        "Kolkata Knight Riders",
        22,
        "2013-05-19T14:30:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5001544,
                39
            ]
        ],
        0,
        0,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T15:03:26.2830000",
            0
        ],
        0,
        "/sports/cricket/indian_premier_league"
    ],
    [
        2417259,
        "El Jaish",
        "Al Rayyan ",
        19,
        "2013-05-19T14:00:00.0000000",
        [
            [
                5001502,
                39
            ]
        ],
        1,
        2,
        1,
        [
            0,
            0,
            "2013-05-19T14:06:27.8300000",
            0
        ],
        0,
        "/sports/volleyball/friendlies_international"
    ]
],
[
    [
        1,
        "Soccer",
        1,
        1,
        [
            "1x2",
            "Asians",
            "O/U"
        ]
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Basketball",
        2,
        2,
        [
            "ML",
            "Spread",
            "O/U"
        ]
    ],
    [
        6,
        "Tennis",
        6,
        6,
        [
            "Winner",
            "Handicap",
            "O/U"
        ]
    ],
    [
        8,
        "Ice Hockey",
        8,
        8,
        [
            "Match Winner",
            "Spread",
            "O/U"
        ]
    ],
    [
        22,
        "Cricket",
        22,
        22,
        [
            "MoneyLine",
            "Spread",
            "O/U"
        ]
    ],
    [
        19,
        "Volleyball",
        19,
        19,
        [
            "ML",
            "Sets Handicap",
            "O/U"
        ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it should be very easy.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: please read question carefully

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DoryZidon Read the question again carefully.